# Is there a word for feeling that one is not properly fufilling one's role?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does there exist a word for when, for example, one is not being masculine or feminine enough, that one is not American enough? In general, that one is not sufficently meeting expectations of what the group that they are a member of is?

Comment: [Impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) might be close to what you are looking for...

Comment: Imposter syndrome is similar, I was thinking more about feelings of inadequacy instead of feelings of falsehood or fraud.

Comment: Either would work.

Comment: "a word for feeling that one is not properly fulfilling one's [gender] role?" : *shame*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **inadequate**:

> Lacking the quality or quantity required; insufficient for a purpose.
>
> (of a person) unable to deal with a situation or with life.
>
> ‘*a sad, solitary, inadequate man*’
>
> ‘*I felt like a fraud, inadequate to the task*’

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inadequate)

Here is an example of use: [The **inadequate male** in D. H. Lawrence's *The Rainbow*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00396072).

Answer (score 0):

**inept**  and **ineptness**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ineptness)

> the quality of having the wrong properties for a specific purpose

As in:  [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=lJCKDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT129&ots=HLC9FKlBY-&dq=%22feelings%20of%20%20ineptness%22&pg=PT129#v=onepage&q=%22feelings%20of%20%20ineptness%22&f=false)

> ... Izard, an emotion theorist, describes
>   experiences shame produces, including **feelings of ineptness**,
>   incapacity, and not belonging.